# jQuery validation using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, jquery-validate

I have a string format like "firstname lastname(email)" and I want to validate the entered value according to this format using jQuery. Hows it is possible? I have tried many things but those are not working properly.

Comment: If you've tried 'many things', then show us those things.

Comment: give one example of string which you want to validate,
and make proper explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this regular expression

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/wTMv3/260/)**

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+ )+([a-zA-Z])+([\(])+([0-9a-zA-Z]+([_.-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.,-]*(.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+(\))+$/

$.validator.addMethod("username_email",function(value,element){
   return this.optional(element) || /^([a-zA-Z]+ )+([a-zA-Z])+([\(])+([0-9a-zA-Z]+([_.-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.,-]*(.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+(\))+$/i.test(value); 
},"enter firstname lastname(email)");
```

**[Jquery Validation with Regular Expressions](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/01/jquery-validation-with-regular.html)**

Comment: how to implement this in jquery validate function

Comment: @shashank, are you using jquery validation plugin?

Comment: yes I am using jQuery plugin.

Comment: please check the updated code - you can also refer this link http://www.9lessons.info/2010/01/jquery-validation-with-regular.html

Comment: First argument: Current value. Second argument: Validated element. Third argument: Parameters., you can simply try using `function(value){}` http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod

Comment: I have done so but my validate method message is overriding the addMethod message like "enter firstname lastname(email)" message is not being shown

Comment: please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/wTMv3/260/

Comment: Hey do you know how to choose theme for autocomplete suggestion list

Comment: sorry, I don't but you should refer this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to accurately and concisely validate an email. An absolutely correct regex would be very long (and most email servers don't support all formats of email address that the RFC defines anyways). You can assume the email is *a sequence of valid characters, then an at-sign, then a sequence of valid characters*. If the regex for email is `/[\w.+-]+\@[\w.]+/`, then the full regex (if you want to forbid a middle name) is

```
/[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+\([\w.+-]+\@[\w.]+\)/
```